# RSpec: How to properly test class method that loops through a collection / calls instance method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, rspec-rails

Consider the following class and class method:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
    scope :active, -> { where(deleted: false) }

    class << self
      def some_class_method
        active.each do |foo|
          foo.some_instance_method
        end
      end
    end
end
```

what is the best practice to test such a method in RSpec?  What I have learned thus far suggests that I should make sure that each active instance of Foo *receives* a call to `some_instance_method`, but if I were to make an expectation regarding `Foo.some_class_method`, to my knowledge I cannot assert a nested expectation about any instance of Foo.

Any help would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

The approach I would take is to separately test `some_instance_method`, like:

```
it 'should return some value' do
  expect(foo.some_instance_method).to eq('some value')
end
```

You could then run the class method and test that the transformations happened as expected:

```
context 'Foo#some_class_method' do
  it 'should have some effect' do
    expect(some_comparison_variable).to eq('some_before_state')
    Foo.some_class_method
    expect(some_comparison_variable).to eq('some_after_state')
  end
end
```

Comment: That crossed my mind, but doesn't that effectively double-test `some_instance_method`?

Comment: There is no harm in testing the same method twice.

Comment: You can do `expect(some_instance_of_Foo).to receive(:some_instance_method)` the second time.